# Using trim on empty string in where clause in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to figure out why the below SQL statement does not return the value do in oracle

```
Select 'do' from dual
where trim('  ') = ''
```

Where as

```
Select 'do' from dual
where trim(' a ')='a'
```

returns the value do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

because `trim('  ')` returns `null` and not `''`

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/3610)

> In Oracle 8, there is no such thing as a zero-length string. Any zero-length string, either from a function call or the literal '', is treated as null.

[Source](http://thunderguy.com/semicolon/2003/04/26/oracle-empty-string-null/)

Answer (score 1):

Zero-length string is treated as null, and you cannot compare nulls through (in)equality in Oracle, as they are treated in special way.

Doc reference: [NULLS in conditions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements005.htm#g194888)

Therefore, this one expectedly doesn't work:

```
Select 'do' from dual where trim('  ') = ''
```

Try this instead:

```
10:39:58 SYSTEM@dwh-prod> select * from dual where trim('   ') is null 
10:40:02   2  /                                                        

D                                                                      
-                                                                      
X                                                                      

Elapsed: 00:00:00.07                                                   
10:40:04 SYSTEM@dwh-prod> select * from dual where '' is null          
10:40:11   2  /                                                        

D                                                                      
-                                                                      
X                                                                      

Elapsed: 00:00:00.02                                                   
10:40:11 SYSTEM@dwh-prod>
```

Comment: Thanks, That was helpful. Worked when the condition `is NULL` as opposed to when I set `trim('  ') = null`. Now why is that?

Comment: @nJoshi because `'' is null` yields true, though `'' = null` yields *unknown*. even `null = null` yields unknown. Check out the comparison results table at the link I provided.

Comment: That makes sense, but there are a lot differences between MS-SQl and Oracle

Comment: @nJoshi isn't it that there are supposed to be some? )

Comment: Nope, its different. Here is a sample for MS-SQL server. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/094b3/3/0)

Comment: I mean, they are supposed to be different from each other )

Comment: oh.. Now I understand what you meant.